# Using parenthesis/bracket/curly brace for probability measure?

Tags: probability

I saw some people use $Pr\{\}$ (with curly braces) to denote a probability measure. I wonder if it is because the argument of a probability measure is a set, rather than a real number, for example?

I also saw people use $Pr()$ and $Pr[]$. Are there any differences among the three notations?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there are no differences. If the "_setness_" is to be emphasized then we write $Pr(\{.\})$ where the outer parentheses are arbitrary. Just like putting the $r$ after $P$ is a question of taste -- not to be questioned.

Comment: Do not worry too much about it. Personally I abbreviate e.g. $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq x\}$ by $\{X\leq x\}$ and $\Pr(\{X\leq x\})$ on its turn by $\Pr(X\leq x)$, but it is just a matter of taste and (maybe even more) how I was raised.

Comment: I had the same question but could not spot anything at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11 to help

Comment: I am going to prefer the smooth because it does not need to be escaped when typing latex.